# Using jQuery to add DOM elements based on option:selected choice

Tags: html, jquery, html-select, selected

I want to insert elements into the DOM after a named div based on the choice in a drop down option list.

Here is my code to test this.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jsstuff/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(funtion(){('#testselect').change(function(){
    var selid = $(this).find('#testselect :selected').val();
    if (selid == "Yes"){
        $("<div><span>test option</span></div>").insertAfter("#inner");
    }
}
)
)
   
</script>
<title>Untitled 2</title>

</head>

<body>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <select id="testselect" name="testselect">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>    
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

It is not working.

Comment: What *exactly* is not working? Do you get any syntax errors? Does anything happen? Be *specific*.

Comment: I am sorry I should have been more specific. Nothing happened. The div was not inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are a few mistakes in the code you posted. There are a few simple errors like spelling and a missing $ inside the event handler.  Also the way you're getting the value of the dropdown can be simplified. Here's an example.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('#testselect').change(function() {
            var selid = $(this).val();
            if (selid == "Yes"){
                $("<div><span>test option</span></div>").insertAfter($("#inner"));
            }
        });
    });

</script>
<title>Untitled 2</title>

</head>

<body>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <select id="testselect" name="testselect">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>    
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your function:

```
$('#testselect').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Yes") {
        $("<div><span>test option</span></div>").insertAfter("#inner");
    }
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/e8QM8/)**

`.find()` looks at descendant elements, so your `$(this).find('#testselect :selected')` won't match anything since `this` here is already `#testselect`. What you might have been thinking of was `$(this).find('option:selected').val()`, but `$(this).val()` is shorter and more commonly used. Note that repeatedly changing the select element will repeatedly add more test option divs. So you may be better of having a set deiv and just show/hide it.